# SLDS - InputField MultiSelect PickList

Tags: visualforce, slds

I am re-styling existing VF pages. I have an inputField that is rendered as multiSelectPickList. I tried using 'slds-dueling-list', but I am not sure the code is right. There is no example code on the inputField with SLDS style class on lightning design system site. Does anyone has sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still extract the code that they use to generate that particular HTML markup. The only issue is that it's still in development and may change.

Just right-click and select "Inspect" (or similar for non-chrome browsers).

You will then be able to copy the HTML code.

Here is the code I extracted to build my own DuellingPicklist implementation, with the SVG buttons replaced with `lightning:icons`. The code is static but with some effort, you should be able recreate this functionality.

By some effort, I mean quite a lot. My version is over 500 loc in helper class.

Here is the static code:

```
<div class="slds-dueling-list">
  <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="drag-live-region" aria-live="assertive"/>
  <div class="slds-assistive-text" id="option-drag-label">Press space bar when on an item, to move it within the list. CMD plus left and right arrow keys, to move items between lists.</div>
  <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
    <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-3">First Category</span>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__options" role="application">
      <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-3" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
        <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
          <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
            <span class="slds-media__body">
              <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 1">Option 1</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon-container slds-button_icon-small" title="Right" >
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:right" size="small" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" />
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection to Second Category</span>
    </button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon-container slds-button_icon-small" title="Left" >
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:left" size="small" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" />
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection to First Category</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
    <span class="slds-form-element__label" id="label-4">Second Category</span>
    <div class="slds-dueling-list__options" role="application">
      <ul aria-describedby="option-drag-label" aria-labelledby="label-4" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" role="listbox">
        <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
          <div class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" draggable="true" role="option" tabindex="0">
            <span class="slds-media__body">
              <span class="slds-truncate" title="Option 4">Option 4</span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-dueling-list__column">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon-container slds-button_icon-small" title="Up" >
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:up" size="small" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" />
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection up</span>
    </button>
    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon-container slds-button_icon-small" title="Down" >
        <lightning:icon iconName="utility:down" size="small" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" />
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Move Selection down</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Casper. Just wondering if it is possible to use it with no SLDS, I mean the normal Visual Force way only for this component? I tried that too but since slds is applied at page level, the arrow buttons still do not show as expected.

Comment: No, I don't think so. You'll need to build a custom duelling select list and add it using lightning out. You can use this markup above + combined with my duellng select list here: https://github.com/rapsacnz/DualSelect.